# No intellisense for razor pages (.cshtml) in VS 2015 Nancy project

Tags: c#, razor, nancy

I have a project in Nancy that uses razor pages. Nancy.Viewengines.Razor nuget is installed, I have implemented IRazorConfiguration, the razor pages render correctly and I have intellisense in Visual Studio 2013.

But in Visual Studio 2015 I have no intellisense when editing razor pages. No problem during runtime, the reports render correctly.

How can I make intellisense for .cshtml work again in Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: Are you using the full name space?

Comment: It doesn't even recognize `@inherits`.

Comment: Are you referencing it in your project?

Comment: If I don't reference it, it would fail on runtime, no?

Comment: Fair point, dumb question on my end... Did you follow the setup instructions on Nancy's website? I'm sure you've already done this but that's about all I've got. Sorry, hope someone else can help you more! Good luck! https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Razor-View-Engine

Comment: Yes, I've gone through that page. I appreciate your help nonetheless :) Do you use VS 2015 with nancy and razor? I need to know if it's a problem in my machine.

Comment: I don't unfortunately, sorry I couldn't be of more help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 solved the issue. Intellisense is back on razor (.cshtml) pages.

Answer (score 0):

I find that adding this to the top of each Razor view fixes intellisense for me in VS 2015 update 3:

```
@inherits Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.NancyRazorViewBase
```